# gnome-control-center not running

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, settings

Today, just after a software upgrade which involved `samba-libs`, the `gnome-conrol-center` utility didn't start anymore when I tried to launch it from the small "tools" icon located at the top-right corner of the screen
(under a `gnome3` session).

Running instead `gnome-control-center` from a `gnome-terminal` works fine,
although I got the following message on the terminal itself:

```
  (gnome-control-center:6766): network-cc-panel-WARNING **: 
  16:52:47.248: Error connecting to ModemManager: Errore nel chiamare 
  StartServiceByName per org.freedesktop.ModemManager1: 
  GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit dbus- 
  org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.service not found.
```

Is this related with the failure in launching the program from the icon?

My system is a `Linux Fedora 29` and I work in a `gnome-session`.
`gnome-control-center` installed on my system is `gnome-control-center-3.30.3-1.fc29.x86_64` and `samba-libs` is `samba-libs-4.9.8-0.fc29.x86_64`

Can anyone understand where is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somewhere it was suggested to execute `killall` on the `gnome-control-center` process, but this didn't work in my case: the process doesn't hang; it simply doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue: there was something wrong inside the `.local` directory in my
`$HOME`. I didn't investigate what, but it has been enough to remove that directory and let the system create a new one to get all working. I had only to pay the reintroduction by hand of my passwords for the mail client `evolution`.